# Event time vs Processing time in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I am having a hard time understanding the difference between event time and processing time in Apache Kafka.

For instance, Apache Flink works with watermarks and time is not synchronized with the progress of real wall-clock time until you emit a watermark. Only after this, the time progresses (I hope I'm right).

I know Kafka doesn't use watermarks. I read through the documentation but can't find any info about processing time in Kafka apart from stamping the events with the time of the event when it occurs or the time the event is processed. Are these notions only at the conceptual level in Kafka event processing?

Comment: event: when generated; processing: when acted upon ... The broker also has settings to change which timestamp is actually written on disk (event creation, or log-append)

Comment: I know the difference but I don't know how Kafka behaves when you change the time processing semantics.

Comment: The brokers themselves just store the timestamp. KStreams has a TimestampExtractor that can be used for windowing and other processing workloads, similar to Flink, if thats what you mean